# Unpack parameter pack into string view

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17, string-view

It is possible to unpack a value template parameter pack of type char into a (compile time) string.
How does one acquire a `string_view` into that string?

What I want to do:

```
int main()
    {
    constexpr auto s = stringify<'a', 'b', 'c'>();
    constexpr std::string_view sv{ s.begin(), s.size() };
    return 0;
    }
```

Try:

```
template<char ... chars>
constexpr auto stringify()
    {
    std::array<char, sizeof...(chars)> array = { chars... };
    return array;
    }
```

Error:

```
15 : <source>:15:30: error: constexpr variable 'sv' must be initialized by a constant expression
constexpr std::string_view sv{ s.begin(), s.size() };
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
15 : <source>:15:30: note: pointer to subobject of 's' is not a constant expression
```

Is there a way to get a the behaviour in the `main` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails to work as constexpr because `s` array is located on the stack so its address is not known at compile time. To fix you can declare `s` as `static`.

[Check this solution in online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ccX9X1KKPDTx93bC)

Comment: Why does this compile fine then?
`constexpr const char* myData = "hello";
 constexpr std::string_view sv(myData);`
myData is also a variable on the stack and yet it works

Comment: @Valentin In this case data stored in globally-allocated array for string literal `"hello"`, only pointer to this array is stored on the stack.

Comment: That makes sense. But then how's `constexpr std::array s {'a', 'b'};` different from just `std::array s {'a', 'b'};`? What's the benefit of defining it as constexpr if you can't use it anyway? And why is it allowed?

Comment: @Valentin It would work fine as long as you don't need the address on the stack, for example you can `constexpr auto avg{(s[0] + s[1]) / 2};`

Comment: Thank you very much. This was definitely one of the harder problems I encountered.

Answer (score 1):

This code compiles in clang, though GCC still throws an (incorrect I think) error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string_view>

template<char... chars>
struct stringify {
    // you can still just get a view with the size, but this way it's a valid c-string
    static constexpr std::array<char, sizeof...(chars) + 1> str = { chars..., '\0' };
    static constexpr std::string_view str_view{&str[0]};
};

int main() {
    std::cout << stringify<'a','b','c'>::str_view;
    return 0;
}
```

Although it generates a warning about the "sub-object." (chars...) The other answer explains the reason this works.